# django form queryset filter using request user

Tags: django, forms, filter, django-queryset

I want to filter queryset using current user data but it's return only a Nonetype
Suppose When I remove None its shows the error  user can't recognize

In Forms.py

```
class oldenquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=enquiry
        fields=['product','type','created_at']
        widgets={
            'created_at':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
        }
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(oldenquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        employee = emp.objects.filter(branch=user.admin.branch_name).values_list('firstname',flat=True)
        print (employee)
        self.fields['created_by'].queryset=emp.objects.filter(branch=user.admin.branch_name).values_list('firstname',flat=True)
```

views.py

I want to get the emp data is similar to admin branch

```
def enquirys(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=oldenquiryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
         return render(request,'enquirys.html',{'form':form})
```

models.py

I have linked the admin,emp to user model

```
class admin(models.Model):
user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
firstname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,null=False)
created_by=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
phonenumber=models.TextField(default='',null=False,unique=True)
photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='admin_photo/',default='user.jpg')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
branch= models.ForeignKey(branch,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
branch_name= models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
def __str__(self):
 return self.firstname

class emp(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    firstname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,null=False)
    lastname=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,null=False)
    gender=(
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
        ('O','Others'),
        )
    gender=models.CharField(choices=gender, default='',max_length=10)
    dob=models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    created_by=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    phonenumber=models.TextField(default='',null=False,unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    branch=models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
```

Comment: Please share the code where you instantiate your `oldenquiryForm`. It seems you do not pass the user to it.

Comment: How do you use this form? Can you share the *view* where you use this?

Comment: Furthermore please share your `emp`, and `admin` model (and your user model if you used a custom one).

Comment: i have updated my model and views

Answer (score 1):

You should call the super constructor without the `user` field, so removing it from the named parameters before, for example by adding `user=None` to the signature:

```
class OldEnquiryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super(oldenquiryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['created_by'].queryset = emp.objects.filter(branch=user.admin.branch_name)

    class Meta:
        model=enquiry
        fields=['product','type','created_at']
        widgets={
            'created_at':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
        }
```

Then in the view, you construct the form with the logged in user as `user`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def enquirys(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OldEnquiryForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = OldEnquiryForm(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'enquirys.html',{'form':form})
```

Probably you should also construct a model for the branch and use a `ForeignKey` to implement [*database normalization* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.